# Installation failed due to following error

Tags: android

Application is not installing in my mobile due to this error. How to fix it?

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/lasyavaliveti/Desktop/multipleproductslive/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 29466656' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
```

Answer (score 0):

It is either there is no space on your android phone. so free up space Or your android API version does not support instant run, so go to settings and uncheck instant run.

Answer (score 0):

run UnistallAll in Gradle.
If you installed before then could not install now.
It uninstalls the previous application.
Then press `Shift+F10`  (Run)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check these

1. Build -> clean -> Rebuild otherwise invalidate caches and restart(It will works on almost all cases)
2. make sure your build variants are same for all modules
   (build variants may be changed for a module will cause the same issue)